# Returning NULL value while searching in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, rdbms, oop

I am using Hibernate 3 as my databse layer framework.

I am facing some problem while searching for a record using the below code.

```
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(
   User.class).add(
    Restrictions.ilike("userType", userType));
   criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("status", "1"));

  List<User> list = (List<User>) this
    .getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
  if (list == null || list.size() <= 0)
  return null;

return list;
```

Here it returning null value. Even thought there are records exists in table.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: Do you mean `1` instead of `"1"`?

Comment: Can you add an example row from your table?

Comment: USERNAME USERTYPE STATUS
narendra     1      1         

suresh       2      1            

mani         1      0

Answer (score 0):

I think the status is an enum, in which case you need to search it as an integer not a string. REmove the quotes around the 1.

Also give the table details and the class structure, if the above doesn't solve the problem